Seeking Sources on Integration Using Euler's Formula
I am particularly interested in the method of integration involving Euler's formula. I came across to this technique on Wikipedia, but unfortunately, the provided reference paper link is broken: Wikipedia: Integration using Euler's formula.
Could anyone recommend textbooks or articles that cover the integration technique using Euler's formula in detail?

@Moo: Yes! Thank you very much!

Not a paper or article, but a quick YouTube search seems to bring up a few results on what you're looking for like this one.

@Accelerator: Yes, I've watched several videos about this technique. However, I wanted something more academic that I could cite in an article since I'm working on a technique that is closely related to integrating using Euler's formula.

The first two Google results when I search "euler's formula article paper integration" bring up this and this. I didn't read these or research the authors' backgrounds, but hopefully, these would be better than YouTube sources since YouTube isn't always the most reliable when it comes to learning math/science formally.
